# How to append a form with dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to append so i'm practicing and I have a form with a dropdown. When the user click the Add Question button the textarea along with the dropdown will append. Can't seem to be working, please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtxwLcgn/

```
$( "#add" ).click(function() {

var newElement = "<form id ="ques"><label>Question:</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Enter a question"></textarea><br><select name="choice" id="choice" onchange="selectorchecker(this)"><option value="">Select choices</option><option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option><option value="radiobtn">Radio Button</option></select></form>";

$( "#ques" ).append( $(newElement) );
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine. You just need to import/select jquery which which you are referencing in your code. In javascript section of your jsfiddle, just select `JavaScript + jQuery 3.3.1` from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the quotation marks `"` inside the `newElement` string with `'`. Because you are using `"` to start the string and `"` inside the string as well, parts of the string are being left out.

Answer (score 0):

Please, also add the jquery to your fiddle. It seems to me, that is missing now.
I am seeing an error, like: ***Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined***

After I have added, It worked smoothly.

[Fiddle Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKcNK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code and solution to your query:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jf48xmsp/)

```
You can try clicking on "Append" button and form with all its content will append.
Only you need to make sure that your button need to be outside of form tag.
Hope it works for you !
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line before starting your JS script.You code  will work as you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```